# Number of line in CATextlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, catextlayer

I have a dynamic string with dynamic length. I use CATextlayer to draw it in a view. I set wrapped = YES, but I don't know how to check the number of line of CATextlayer in a view to set dynamic frame for another view. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSString's` `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`

```
[yourString sizeWithFont:fontHere constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(fixedWidthForLayerTextHere, 999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```